# MySQL date_add REPEAT loop error

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE incDate(fromdate date, todate date)

SET currDay = fromdate;
SET endDAY = todate;

REPEAT
  SET currDay = DATE_ADD(currDay, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  INSERT INTO `dentists`.`dayT` (`day`) VALUES (currDay);
UNTIL currDay > endDAY END REPEAT;

END
```

But MySQL gives me the following error:

```
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'currDay'
```

Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[User-defined variables must be prefixed with `@`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

```
SET @currDay = fromdate, @endDAY = todate;
```